# Can we have a form_dropdown function embedded in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter. I need to have a `form_dropdown` embedded inside javascript.I have a table with a button add row.
When I click add I replicate the same row above. In my view page I have a javascript to add the dynamic table row.
Now I could not have a drop-down in it.I have a controller file where I pass a data that should be displayed as drop-down box.
My controller function:

```
class Admin_billing extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('billing_model');

        if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }

    public function ticket($id)
    {
    $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('client_detail');
        $id=$this->uri->segment(4);

        $data['id']=$this->uri->segment(4);

        $data['employee']=$this->billing_model->emp_name();

        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/billing/ticket_page';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
     }
}
```

My model function:

```
<?php
class billing_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();

    }
public function emp_name()
    {

        $this->db->select('employee.first_name');
    $this->db->from('employee');
    $this->db->group_by('employee.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array(); 
    }


}
?>
```

Here I have a emp_name function to get the employee name from my database.
My view page:

```
<script>
function displayResult() {
    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = '<td>form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"')</td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}

</script>
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
      }

      ?>
<table id="test">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <td style="width:80px;">Employee</td>
            <td style="width:35px;">Start time</td>
            <td style="width:35px;">Id</td>
            <td style="width:145px;">Description</td>
            <td style="width:45px;">Type></td>
            <td style="width:45px;">qty prch></td>
            <td style="width:45px;">qty used</td>
            <td style="width:70px;">Price</td>
            <td style="width:70px;">discount></td>
            <td style="width:70px;">Tax></td>
            <td style="width:70px;">Total</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pid[]"  value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="type[]" class="type" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty_prch[]" class="qty_prch" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty_used[]" class="qty_used" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="discount[]" class="discount" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" style="width:70px;"/></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>

            </table>

            <div id="add_row">
        <button onClick="displayResult()" class="add_r"></button>
                </div>
```

This is my view page in the above table My first field is a dropdown php code. This works for static row in my table.When I use javascript to add new row I could not get a dropdown.How to handle this?Can someone help me code?

Answer (score 0):

First at all PHP is server side language. If you append to html your row only in javascript no php is executed.

You need use ajax for this. Solution with jQuery:

1. On server side (php) you need to prepare url (function) for serve a new row snipped data.
2. On buton onClick event trigger jQuery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax. Url param point to prepared url.
3. After ajax request is done you set response data as new row to your table.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "DOMAIN/newRow",
  })
  .done(function(data) {
      $('table#test tbody').append(data);
    }
  });
```

PHP (in your admin billing controller)

I am not verry familiar with cakePHP, so simple. You need write function which returns generated row html.

```
public function newRow()
{
     $options_employee = 'prepare this variable here';
     $dropdown = form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');

     // Send data to browser (return is only for demonstration)
     return '<tr><td>' . $dropdown . '</td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: I have less idea about ajax can you help me with some code?@Samuel Kelemen

Comment: Ok I will try with this. :)

Comment: In newRow() funciton send result data to browser in cakePHP way. By Cake documentation something like $this->response->body('your generated html'); return $this->response;

Comment: Is that the ajax code ? this should be in html page?

Comment: No $this->response->body('your generated html'); return $this->response is php code and needs to be in newRow() function

Comment: I could get that in your answer You have a ajax code 3rd step. When I trigger that ajax code in html page it calls my domain/function and returns a new row?

Comment: Yes, execute it after onClick button event

Comment: .done(function(data)) means the response from my controller?

Comment: Yes data variable will be html code sended from your controller.

Comment: Is my above approach wrong? I mean my question. Why that do not work?

Comment: This is not working for me. What is that variable data in ajax function?@Samuel Kelemen